# Как показывать уведомление по очереди?

Tags: android, android-notification

Допустим у меня есть array времен. Назовем ее `timeList` . Она содержит в себе следующее: `{"11:40","11:55","16:15","20:05"}` . Сперва, я должен показать notification в `11:40` , потом в `11:55` и так далее.Каждый notification имеет свой `title` и `text`. И они не должны обновляться(то есть если notification показался в `11:40` и user не убрал или не нажал на него, то следующий notification в `11:55` , должен расположиться рядом с ним). Я знаю как показывать notification используя `AlarmManager` и `BroadcastReceiver`. Но не могу представить,как решить эту задачу. Но есть такое предположение: Когда приложение открывается в первый раз , я устанавливаю alarm, чтобы показать уведомление по `index= 0` ( где `index` -индекс массива `timeList`). Когда первое уведомление было показано , мне следует обновить `index` и установить alarm на следующее уведомление и так далее , до конца. В конце ,отменяется все операции и уведомление больше показываться не будет. Но я не представляю, как написать эту идею. Как решить эту проблему? Правильный ли мой подход? Мне нужен `Service` для этого? Можете ли вы дать конкретные шаги для решения этой проблемы? Ниже мой код:

```
     public void setAlarm(){

      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance() ;

    //храню id в Preferense
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timeList.get(id).hour_of_day) ;


    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timeList.get(id).minute) ;


    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,timeList.get(id).second) ;


    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyHopingReceiver.class) ;



    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),3*60*1000,pendingIntent);
}
```

Метод `onReceiver` `BroadCastReceiver-а`:

```
   @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context,SomeActivity.class);

    repeatingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeatingIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setAutoCancel(true);



    notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

    //Как здесь обновить index и удалить предыдущий alarm,а потом 
    //установить новый?













}
```

Answer (score 4):

У вас проблема, в том, что вы используете один и тот же `id` в

```
notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build()); //id=100
```

Как пишется в документации:

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

То есть вам надо в каждом новом уведомлении присваивать новый идентификатор, иначе так и будете затирать старое уведомление.

Предложу для генерации идентификатора использовать:

```
AtomicInteger notificationId=new AtomicInteger(100);
//blah-blah
notificationManager.notify(notificationId.getAndIncrement(),builder.build());
```